# how to show output in javascript

Tags: javascript

I created an application using HTML and  JavaScript. I have a couple of questions on how a program can show output and how it can validate input.

For showing output I have things like using the `console.log` statement, and using the `alert`. I was just wondering what is considered showing an output. would the hiding of different elements be an example of an output as when the user decides to click on certain features of the site others are hidden. also would the use of `innerHTML` be another example of an output?

Comment: You can hide and show elements, you can update the text and HTML of the DOM, you can show alerts, you can open new windows or tabs. All of these would be consiered showing output.

Comment: Its not a coding problem its a question that I have been asked on different ways to show output

Comment: sounds like a philosophical question.

Comment: Is this an interview question? Why did you say that you created a website when it has nothing to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to render output on front side..
if you have small data to show on front side then you can render all data at once on front and you can do show hide data based on user selection. so it will be fast for user experience.

But if you have large data to render on front, then it will be good if you pull particular data based on user selection at same time..(innerhtml)..